# Autotools: How to add a shared library .so?

Tags: fortran, shared-libraries, config, autotools, .so

I tried to add my Fortran modules and a shared library (.so) into an extensive library. The code does not complain about the modules. It knows where to find .mod files. However, I do not know what option should be put in `configure.ac` to make it consider the shared library .so.

By far, I tried the following commands separately in configure.ac but no success:

Option 1)

```
medys_LDADD = -L/PathToDirectory -lnamelib
```

Option 2)

```
LDADD=PathToDirectory/namelib.so
```

Option 3)

```
AM_LDADD = PathToDirectory/namelib.so
```

Comment: Are you using Automake? We probably need a fair bit more detail (see [mre]) about your project configuration.

Comment: @francescalus, yes, I do use automake. Whenever I make a change, I first do "autoreconf -vi" and second "make". I will have a look at the link you sent, but as the library is not open source, I don't have permission to share the file related to it. In the main directory there is a Makefile.am and SUBDIRS option. Inside each directory, there is a "Makefile.mk" file. I put my modules and the shared library that I use inside a new directory and I made a "Makefile.mk" inside it. I followed what was done inside other "Makefile.mk"s, so the source and module file's names are listed there.

Comment: It appears that you are trying to link your shared library to an application (as opposed to another shared library).  In that case, both options (1) and (2) look ok to me, but the former would be more conventional.  With that said, we (still) don't have enough information to go on.  In particular, do note that the name "Makefile.mk" has no particular significance to the Autotools.  That is a convention of your particular build system, and we have no way of knowing how those files are (intended to be) used.